# Bigquery Java API: Add a column while loading data

Tags: google-bigquery

While loading data from a CSV file into Bigquery via the Java API, is there a way to add an extra column?

For example:

```
Add a column with "AsofDate" with the current date?
Or "LoadedBy" with <Username>?
```

Comment: How do you load the data from CSV and what API calls you do?

Comment: I upload the CSV to cloud storage and then into bigquery using the java api's. com.google.api.services.bigquery

Answer (score 0):

If you do the straight "upload from CSV"... then no I don't think you can do that. There are a couple of easy solutions though :

1- to upload from GCS to BQ, don't use the API call, read your csv manually and "build your table" as you go.

2- You can use the API to upload your data, then use BigQuery to "requery" your data, putting the result into another table, and adding whatever you need as other columns

Comment: I'm using your second solution currently. Doing it manually is not an option as we are loading new data every hour. I was hoping there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Not that I know of, unfortunately.